# Discriminator problem on Views inherit from table

Tags: c#, sql-server, view, entity-framework-core, discriminator

I use EF Core in my project and have a base class Person.

In addition to the Person, I have multiple views inherited from the base class because I want the fields and relationships of the base class.

The views contains computed column, that i defined in the CREATE statement of the view, mostly status or Ids

```
//Simplified for the example

public class Person {
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   
   public Guid BId {get; set;}
   public Class B { get; set;}
} 

public class PersonView : Person {
  
   public PersonStatus Status {get; set;}
}

public class PersonNextView : Person {
  
   public PersonStatus Status {get; set;}
   
   public Guid? NextId {get; set;}
   public virtual Person? {get; set;}

}
```

The problem is that EF Core makes Discriminator on my query when I query one of the Classes above, which seems strange.

```
// Query: 

 _context.PersonView.Where(...).ToListAsync(...);
```

This will be translated with Discriminator, but shouldn't EF Core only query the view?

Especially on `.Includes(...)` are big SQL queries created, with Joins on all Views.

Questions:

**Why do I make inheritance views?**
Because I use HotChocolate as my GraphQL API and use the view types to generate filters/sorting for them.

```
 [UseFiltering(typeof(PersonView))]
 [UseSorting(typeof(PersonView))]
 public IQueryable<PersonView> PersonFilter(...) {
   ...
 }
```

Database used:
SQL Server